# Can I replace the derivative operator in the Dirac equation with momentum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, fourier-transform, dirac-equation

Can I replace the derivative operator in the Dirac equation with momentum?

$$ (i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi(x) = 0 $$

$$ (\gamma^\mu p_\mu - m) \tilde{\psi}(p) = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we posit a solution to the Dirac equation of the form,

$$\psi = u(\vec p)e^{-ip\cdot x}$$

then one finds that the four-component spinor $u(\vec p)$ must satisfy the equation,

$$(\gamma^\mu p_\mu -m) u(\vec p) = 0$$

and we call such a solution a positive frequency solution. Furthermore, we can also make the substitution, $\psi = \mathscr{v}(\vec p) e^{ip\cdot x}$, in which case it satisfies the equation,

$$(\gamma^\mu p_\mu + m) \mathscr{v}(\vec p) = 0$$

for the negative frequency solution. As an example, if we consider the positive frequency solution, with mass $m$ and 3-momentum $\vec p = 0$, one has,

$$u(\vec p ) = \sqrt{m} \begin{pmatrix}
\xi\\ 
\xi
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\xi$ is a 2-component spinor, which determines the spin. For example, if we want it to have spin up along the $z$-axis, then it must have eigenvalue $+1$ with respect to the Pauli matrix $\sigma^z$, which would be the case for, $\xi^T = (1,0)$. These spinors $u$ and $\mathscr{v}$ are the ones which appear in the Feynman rules, which we associate to incoming and outgoing fermions.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: yes you can!

Long answer: in the Dirac equation those derivatives are actually the covariant derivatives of a 4 component coordinate vector denoted usually by $X:(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)$. So if we want to be consistent, that momentum which you want to obtain by considering that $-i\hbar d/dx_i\to p_i$ is the **4 momentum**, which, as you probably guessed, has 4 components. $P_\mu=(E/c,-\textbf{p})$, where $c$ is the speed of light and $E$ is the energy.

So indeed, you can replace the derivative with the 4-momentum operator, and you will obtain an eigenvalue equation of the form: $P_{op}\phi=mc\phi$

Comment: No, that's is **not** what happens. What happens is that you write $\psi(x)$ in Fourier transform and separate the variables. In order the equation to still hold then each single coefficient must vanish, ergo the latter equation must hold. Also, you are mixing up the *representation* of the momentum operator on the position basis (as operator on a Hilbert space in QM) with a standard derivative here.